# Change ASP.NET target version from 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reference

Because the hostingprovider I work with only supports ASP.NET 4.0, while I built the project in ASP.NET 4.5, I tried to convert the version to 4.0, but now I have a lot of warnings.

How can I fix this? The warnings mostly say the same, namely:

> The primary reference "DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[key], processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Comment: If you don't want to make a brand-new project and copy in all your code, you would have to fix all the references on your project. Your error says that the project is using references that target a higher .net framework than the one you are using.

Comment: If that are nuget references you can run an Update-Package.

Comment: Which package would that be?

Comment: And where can I find these references at all? I figure it would be something like adjusing the versions in these references to 4.0 or something?

Comment: Change the hosting provider. Simple like that. If my provider would not maintain his servers I would tell him that my business goes to a provider that does.

Comment: Sadly that is something I cannot do, I have to work with what I've got.

Comment: your main solution will be in 4.0 and that is the default and you will perform a final build on this then create a new solution targeting 4.5 and you can use 4.5 so you will have something like project.40 and project.45 and you can open one or the other and fix your code. As a note though, why develop in a language that your deployment server doesn't support. Remember there are people still using VB6 and VS2003 and 2005 etc...

Comment: You already tried to clean your solution(s) and rebuild it (with the new ASP.NET version)?

Comment: Did you run "Update-Package" in the package Manager?